# Efficient way to find & open files deep in a project tree?

Tags: multiple-files, path

Without plugins like `ctrlp` and `NERDTree`, what would be the most efficient way to find and open files deep in a project tree?

Setting the `path` to `**/*` results in useless files in `.git` and other hidden directories, so that appears to be out of the question.

Is there a way to set the path in a *smart* manner, so that it only includes files in `git ls-files` or something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts of my setup:

- enable the wildmenu,

  ```
  set wildmenu
  ```
- make filename-completion skip these files and directories,

  ```
  set wildignore+=*.swp,*.bak
  set wildignore+=*.pyc,*.class,*.sln,*.Master,*.csproj,*.csproj.user,*.cache,*.dll,*.pdb,*.min.*
  set wildignore+=*/.git/**/*,*/.hg/**/*,*/.svn/**/*
  set wildignore+=*/min/*
  set wildignore+=tags,cscope.*
  set wildignore+=*.tar.*
  ```
- make it case-insensitive,

  ```
  set wildignorecase
  ```
- list files and let the user choose with the wildmenu,

  ```
  set wildmode=list:full
  ```
- add the directory of the current file and every directory under the working directory to Vim's `path`,

  ```
  set path=.,**
  ```

  **WARNING! The path option is *extremely* useful. The value above — `.,**` — works for *me* but the languages I use don't have a standard library. The *proper* value depends entirely on *your* needs.**
- a bunch of `:find` mappings, the uppercase variants start the search from the directory of the current file for better performance,

  ```
  nnoremap ,f :find *
  nnoremap ,F :find <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>
  nnoremap ,s :sfind *
  nnoremap ,S :sfind <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>
  nnoremap ,v :vert sfind *
  nnoremap ,V :vert sfind <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>
  ```

And here is how it looks like:

[image: :find]

Comment: Wow, these are some great mappings and settings. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

See `:h :command-completion-custom`

We can adapt the last example to complete only files listed by git.

```
command! -nargs=1 -bang -complete=customlist,GitFindComplete
      \ GitFind edit<bang> <args>

function! GitFindComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
  let search_pattern = "*" . a:ArgLead . "*"
  let shell_cmd = "git ls-files " . shellescape(search_pattern)
  return split(system(shell_cmd), "\n")
endfunction
```

Now you can use auto-completion to open the files listed by git:

```
:GitFind ome_f<Tab>
```

Note that in a custom completion function, we must do more than simply list the files which could be completed.  We must also **filter** the list relative to the current commandline argument `ArgLead`.  In this example, we ask `git` to do the filtering for us, by passing it the argument wrapped in `*` wildcards.

Comment: This is an excellent trick

Answer (score 1):

My method include the following shell function in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
vimf() {
  vim $(find . -name $1)
}
```

Then to open any file deep in the project tree, just type:

```
vimf some_file.c
```